# Troubles on training Haar cascade with LBP

Tags: c++, opencv, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier, lbph-algorithm

I'm trying to train some branch logos with haar_cascade. What I've done is, I've taken 2500 squared pictures of 500 x 500 to populate the samples for `opencv_createsamples`. Then I generate them as:

> opencv_createsamples -info 'logo.info' -vec '../logo.vec' -bg '../Negatives/bg.txt' -w 24 -h 24 -num 2500

in my `logo.info` I've got lines which correspond to the relative path of every picture, with a `1 0 0 500 500` meaning "there's one object between (0,0) and (500, 500)"

then I train the cascade as:

> opencv_traincascade  -data 'cascade/' -vec '../logo.vec' -bg '../Negatives/bg.txt' -numPos 2500 -numNeg 3019 -numStages 25 -featureType **LBP** -w 24 -h 24

with these parameters:

> PARAMETERS:
>
> cascadeDirName: cascade/
>
> vecFileName: ../logo.vec
>
> bgFileName: ../Negatives/bg.txt
>
> numPos: 2500
>
> numNeg: 3019
>
> numStages: 25
>
> precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 256
>
> precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 256
>
> stageType: BOOST
>
> featureType: LBP
>
> sampleWidth: 24
>
> sampleHeight: 24
>
> boostType: GAB
>
> minHitRate: 0.995
>
> maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
>
> weightTrimRate: 0.95
>
> maxDepth: 1
>
> maxWeakCount: 100

And I've got 2 kind of errors:

1. OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (No components/input_variables is selected!) in cvPreprocessIndexArray, file /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp, line 432
   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
   what():  /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp:432: error: (-211) No components/input_variables is selected! in function cvPreprocessIndexArray

[image]

...

[image]

this errors uses to happen when you don't give a significant difference between your *num of images* and your `-num` parameter. So, let's try to give less 100!!

well, when I've adjusted the parameters to not to go out from the array, I get the same type of output than images, but I get this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (tempNode->left) in write, file /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/traincascade/boost.cpp, line 628
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/traincascade/boost.cpp:628: error: (-215) tempNode->left in function write
>
> Aborted

I've tried:

- Changing the destiny size of the images (24x24, 36x36...)
- Changing the `-mode` parameter.
- Trying to put a #positiveSamples < #negativeSamples and #positiveSamples > #negativeSamples

What I have to do, is training obligatory with LBP (not HAAR). Do anyone have any clue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and rebuilding OpenCV solved the problem.